# Suddenly can no longer deploy functions to Firebase project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

using express app as function.  my functions engines:node was set to 12.  I had to upgrade node locally -- so I also updated engines:node to 16.  suddenly couldn't deploy the functions, I reverted back to engines:node 12.  Still can't deploy functions.  Seeing this error:

`Missing URI for HTTPS function in printTriggerUrls. This shouldn't happen`

And a bunch of messages referring to previously deployed functions:

`Could not find image for function`

Extremely frustrated... tried reinstalling all the local npm packages with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that finally worked was to delete all the previously deployed functions and re-deploy all the functions fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command to see the logs

`firebase functions:log`